# Time display issue showing --2560 seconds ago when app runs in US

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I am creating an app in which I need to calculate the difference time between current time and previous time which will come from the database and need to display on list. The app works fine in India, but when the same app runs in US than difference time showing in -2560 seconds, or something like that. Why is this?

The code that I used to calculate the difference between times:

```
var timeAgoInWords = function(date) {
    try {
        var now = Math.ceil(Number(new Date()) / 1000),
            dateTime = Math.ceil(Number(new Date(date)) / 1000),
            diff = now - dateTime,
            str;

        if (diff < 60) {
            return String(diff) + ' seconds ago';
        } else if (diff < 3600) {
            str = String(Math.ceil(diff / (60)));
            return str + (str == "1" ? ' minute' : ' minutes') + ' ago';
        } else if (diff < 86400) {
            str = String(Math.ceil(diff / (3600)));
            return str + (str == "1" ? ' hour' : ' hours') + ' ago';
        } else if (diff < 60 * 60 * 24 * 365) {
            str = String(Math.ceil(diff / (60 * 60 * 24)));
            return str + (str == "1" ? ' day' : ' days') + ' ago';
        } else {
            return Ext.Date.format(new Date(date), 'jS M \'y');
        }
    } catch (e) {
        return '';
    }
};
```

The above function I am calling from an `itemTpl`, the below code is where `CreatedDate` will come from database which I save when a user submits a review comment and am passing as parameter to function.

```
this.posted(Ext.Date.parse(values.CreatedDate, "Y-m-d g:i:s"))

 posted: timeAgoInWords
```

And here's how I store the current date and time into the database:

```
 Ext.Date.patterns = { ISO8601Long: "Y-m-d H:i:s" };
    var date = new Date();
    var now = Ext.Date.format(date, Ext.Date.patterns['ISO8601Long'])
```

Comment: Are you sure this isn't just a timezone issue? Also, use `(new Date()).getTime()` instead of `Number(new Date())`.

Comment: @FrancisAvila They will achieve the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a timezone issue. Since the USA is behind IST, the date in seconds from epoch, is giving you a date in the past. This difference thus is negative, since the date you have entered still has to happen in the USA. It is recommend you change all times to UTC before you do any calculations for finding difference in times. You could also calculate the difference on your own server.